# Android - How to send IR code to jack audio (for ir transmitter)

Tags: android, infrared, remote-control

I have found IR codes of some TV brand in ProntoCCF format and 0x00... format. I want to develop an application that send these codes into my IR transmitter plugged into jack audio. How can I do this? Thanks for reply